# libstdc++ private basic_streambuf constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

According to the libstdc++ c++11 [status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x), Stream buffers are marked as completed.

Looking at the `<streambuf>` that shipped with gcc 4.8 however, the constructor and copy constructor are `private` (line 799). According to § 27.6.3 these should be protected, would changing them to protected when  `__cplusplus >= 201103L` result in nasal demons elsewhere? It does mention [DR 50](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#50), what issues would that cause if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a documentation bug in the status page.

DR 50 is ancient history, the C++11 standard specifies the semantics of the copy operations.

It's not as simple as making libstdc++'s existing functions `protected` though: the assignment operator doesn't do anything so needs work.   But I can't see any reason it would result in nasal demons so if you file a [Bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) report to remind us then it will get fixed.